# how to get the cell row of uitableview on touch down?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to expand a cell when you hold down on it and close it when you lift your finger.

I have it working but it has bugs, so I'm trying to find a different way to do it.  Is there any method that is called when you touch down on a cell?

I tried using this: http://locassa.com/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/

but there's a bug where it doesn't work for some of the cells

Answer (score 0):

If you've set a delegate on your table view, touching a cell would likely select it, yes?

You can catch those select events by overriding:

[`- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a)

If you ***don't*** want to select cells, you could also do something clever like subclass "`UITableViewCell`" and add a "`row`" or "`index`" property to your subclassed cell, then set it to the number you want when the cell is returned via "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try set a Gesture recognition on it for the touch up part?
I have never tried it myself but sounds like it should work?  Let me know :)

Comment: I have all that set up, it's just that I want to get the cell row from somewhere